# To plot 7x10 pictures for review in video

Tags: osx, images, latex, gnuplot

Assume you have 77777 pictures. 
You want to review them and their differences:

- have 7x10 pictures without margins
- to have an image viewer where the minimum browse time can be less than 1.0 s such that image view can reached
- I would like to have some approach which is programmable and system independent.

The following are attempts to do this in OSX.

### Gnuplot

I first thought using *gnuplot* but now getting *bad data* notification in trying to plot png -images:

```
plot for [i=1:232] 'image0'.i.'_1_mT.png'
```

which suggests me that not possible in gnuplot.

Other thought was to use *pgfplots* but not existing in OSX so making Tikz/Tex approach difficult, code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161951/13173).

### Discussion about Image viewers

The default viewers often have problems that you cannot customize their margins for instance:

- QuickLook in OXS (no possible to set margins to zero)
- Xee in OXS - you cannot browse many images at once. There is video stream in this layout but its minimum browse time is too long. I opened a ticket about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/xee/issues/detail?id=493).
- I remember that Shotwell does not have the required features. Nevertheless, I am trying to install its latest version [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/177659/15504).

### Latex approach

- thread about this [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/177569/15504) - problem in getting `pgfplots` working

### ImageMagick

- [solved] thread about getting installing ImageMagick and solving a symlink problem for *compare*, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/177594/15504)

**How can you plot 7x10 pictures without margins?** 
Really, just some basic review tool.

Comment: If you want to programmatically measure the images differences you could use [ImageMagick's compare utility](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/)

Comment: There are dozens of image viewers available, shotwell is one commonly used on gnome. Look around for OSX image viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pictures for review in video...**

**[`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/)** can be used to assemble a set of images into a movie for review.  The frame rate can be set to an interval of your choosing. Also, the video can be scrubbed, stepped through, or be played at various rates with program such as [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/).

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/path/to/png/files"
echo "DIRECTORY:" `pwd`        >  png_to_video-log.txt

# `%04d`   four digits padded with zeros
# `-s WxH` rescale to new WxH values 640x360. defaults to source WxH
# `-framerate FPS` frames per second number
# `-y` overwrite existing output

echo "\n#####################" >> png_to_video-log.txt
echo   "### PNG TO VIDEO ####" >> png_to_video-log.txt
ffmpeg -y -f image2 \
       -framerate 4 \
       -i image_%04d.png \
       -f mp4 \
       -vcodec libx264 \
       -pix_fmt yuv420p \
       output_video.mp4        2>> png_to_video-log.txt

open png_to_video-log.txt
```

See also: [ffmpeg wiki "Create a video slideshow from images"](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Comment: Can you make a video of many videos by this method where are shown parallel many videos side by side?

Comment: 'side-by-side composition' is possible using fmpeg [pad filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad).  See [related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other) Also, a search like "ffmpeg videos side by side" finds more examples.  "Many" should be a matter of building out the command.  "How many" may be "too many"? Unknown, since I've not tried many.

Comment: I ended up using LaTeX for the controlling the structure of inputs. Then, viewing them like you describe.