# Merge two video clips into one, placing them next to each other

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avidemux

I have two video clips. Both are 640x480 and last 10 minutes. One contains background audio, the other one a singing actor. I would like to create a single 10 minute video clip measuring 1280x480 (in other words, I want to place the videos next to each other and play them simultaneously, mixing audio from both clips). I've tried trying to figure out how to do this with ffmpeg/avidemux, but so far I came up empty. They all refer to concatenating when I search for merging.

Any recommendations?

Comment: This answer is great, because it provides not only side-by-side examples but also more advanced grid layouts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/1576548

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
ffmpeg \
  -i input1.mp4 \
  -i input2.mp4 \
  -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' \
  -map '[vid]' \
  -c:v libx264 \
  -crf 23 \
  -preset veryfast \
  output.mp4
```

This essentially doubles the size of `input1.mp4` by padding the right side with black the same size as the original video, and then places `input2.mp4` over the top of that black area with the overlay filter.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/153160/join-videos-split-screen

Comment: What does `-map [vid]` do?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey  `[vid]` is a so-called _linklabel_, which is a defined output link label in the filter graph (the line above with the filter_complex). It maps the output from the complex filter graph to the output file.

Comment: I'm getting `Unrecognized option 'crf'`. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found. If I remove `cr` then `unrecognized option 'preset'`

Comment: Getting `no such filter`

Comment: [vid] not in quotes doesn't work.  -->   -map "[vid]" \

Comment: This works like a charm but a bit more explanation would be helpful.

Comment: I got `Padded dimensions cannot be smaller than input dimensions.`

Comment: What is the benefit of your approach versus using the HStack filter?

Comment: This visually works, but I lost all audio.

Answer (score 124):

To be honest, using the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233833/4697) resulted in a lot of dropped frames for me.

However, using the `hstack` filter_complex produced perfectly fluid output:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack output.mp4
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how to stack more than 2 videos, you can simply specify `hstack=inputs=3`

Comment: What to do when they're of different size? I got "Input 1 height 1080 does not match input 0 height 800" error.

Comment: And `vstack` will stack inputs vertically btw.

Answer (score 36):

This can be done with just two filters and the audio from both inputs will also be included.

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
```

- [hstack](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) will place each video side-by-side.
- [amerge](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) will combine the audio from both inputs into a single, multichannel audio stream, and `-ac 2` will make it stereo; without this option the audio stream may end up as 4 channels if both inputs are stereo.

Comment: Hello, Can I overlay one video on to another video?

Comment: @Nisarg Use the [overlay filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).

Comment: I want upper video little transparent so one can see whats happening in background, Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Hello Sir, Can you care to look [this](http://superuser.com/q/1127002/510107) out.

Comment: I lost audio with the accepted answer. This one works perfectly.

Comment: `hstack` has the limitation that it requires constant resolution, which live videos streamed by Chrome (e.g. with WebRTC) won't have, because Chrome changes resolution dynamically depending on the available bandwidth. Then `hstack` fails. So best of both worlds, use the accepted answer for the video part, and this answer for the audio!

Comment: @j1elo how would that command be?

Answer (score 8):

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 0 -t 5 -i inputVideo1.mp4  
-ss 0 -t 5 -i inputVideo2.mp4  
-i BgPaddingImage.jpg  
-filter_complex "nullsrc=size=720*720[base];[base][2:v]overlay=1,format=yuv420p[base1];[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=345*700[upperleft];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=345*700[upperright];[base1][upperleft]overlay=shortest=1:x=10:y=10[tmp1];[tmp1][upperright]overlay=shortest=1:x=366:y=10"  
-c:a copy -strict experimental  
-ss 0 -t 5 -preset ultrafast -an 
output.mp4
```

Add Two Video Side by side And Also Add OverLay Image That Show On Videos Padding With You can change Background Image `[BgPaddingImage.jpg]` here set your bg image path.

Show This below Video its create from Above command

[image]

Comment: What language is this? How do you run it?

Comment: @muru Check it out now its FFMPEG Command ?? :)

Comment: @Sanjay Usually characters like `[` and `*` would have to be escaped before the command could be understood by a shell. I think that is part of the confusion. What shell are you using?

Comment: bro i was run on android ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

**Gradle Dependency**

```
implementation "com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2"
```

**Code**

*Command to concate two videos side by side into one*

```
val cmd : arrayOf("-y", "-i", videoFile!!.path, "-i", videoFileTwo!!.path, "-filter_complex", "hstack", outputFile.path)
```

*Command to append two videos (one after another) into one*

```
  val cmd : arrayOf("-y", "-i", videoFile!!.path, "-i", videoFileTwo!!.path, "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
                        "[0:v]scale=iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v] scale=iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
                        "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "1920x1080", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-crf", "27",
                        "-q", "4", "-preset", "ultrafast", outputFile.path)
```

*Note* :

> "videoFile" is your first video path.
> "videoFileTwo" is your second video path.
> "outputFile" is your combined video path which is our final output path

*To create output path of video*

```
fun createVideoPath(context: Context): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat(Constant.DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        val imageFileName: String = "APP_NAME_"+ timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir: File? = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()
        }
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, Constant.VIDEO_FORMAT, storageDir)
    }
```

*Code to execute command*

```
try {
            FFmpeg.getInstance(context).execute(cmd, object : ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                override fun onStart() {

                }

                override fun onProgress(message: String?) {
                    callback!!.onProgress(message!!)
                }

                override fun onSuccess(message: String?) {
                    callback!!.onSuccess(outputFile)
                }

                override fun onFailure(message: String?) {
                    if (outputFile.exists()) {
                        outputFile.delete()
                    }
                    callback!!.onFailure(IOException(message))
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    callback!!.onFinish()
                }
            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            
        } catch (e2: FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException) {
           
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please edit your post to indicate which language you used for the proposed code, and ideally a command-line example on how to apply it to the OPs problem.