# Merge two videos using FFMPEG side by side without black portion on top and bottom

Tags: ffmpeg, merge

I have two video files of size 360X406 each, I want to merge them side by side to size 720X406. However the below command generating the video output of size 720X406 but its resolution look different in players and html file.

```
ffmpeg -i video1_360x406.mp4 -vf "[in] scale=360:203 [left]; movie=video2_360x406.mp4, scale=360:203, fade=out:300:30:alpha=1 [right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -b:v 768k split_screen.mp4
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other/521878#521878