# merge two videos into single playing side by side using ffmpeg hstack amerge

Tags: ffmpeg

This command:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v]; \
                        [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" \
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
```

Returns this error:

```
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description
[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[v]; [0:a][1:a]amerge[a] matches no streams.
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other/521878#521878

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the original video file contains an audio track, otherwise use this:

```
[1:a:?]
```

Which means *"skip the audio track if doesn't exist"*.