# ffmpeg: Specifying audio stream as filter input

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use `ffmpeg` to make two videos play next to each other simultaneously with both videos' audio combined. This is the command I'm currently running:

```
$ ffmpeg -i video0.mp4 -i video1.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]vstack[video]; [0:a][1:a]amix=inputs=2[audio]" \
    -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -ac 2 output.mp4
```

When I run this command though, I get the following error:

> ```
> Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:v]vstack[video]; [0:a][1:a]amix=inputs=2[audio] matches no streams.
> ```

It seems like `:a` does not refer to the audio stream. What is the proper way to specify the audio streams of my input videos as input streams for the amix filter?

Comment: Possible Dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other

Comment: I think this will solve your issue https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-June/015662.html

Comment: One (or both) of your videos does not have audio.

Comment: @Gyan that seemed to be the issue. I'm sorry for such a silly question, thank you for all the help!